# SQL - filter records with same name and order by increasing "priority" of another field

Tags: sql

Ok, so I can't find a good way to write the question title, so here is the scenario:
I have a table with records that have a name, a validity date, and other properties.
The unique key for my table is based on name and validity date.

For example, if I have these records:

```
id 1, NAME_A , 2018-01-01
id 2, NAME_A , 2018-02-01
id 3, NAME_A , 2018-03-01
```

And I ask for "NAME_A", 2018-01-15, I should retrieve id 1, because it's the only validity that "existed" at that time.

If I ask for "NAME_A", 2018-02-02, then it would be id 2, because that's the newest validity available.

So, whenever I need a single validity, I filter all the records which validity date is less or equal then the date I want, order them by that date, and get the first top record.

The problem is when I want to retrieve a lot of records. Let's say I want all records, no matter the name, that are valid (I might also want to have additional filters.)

Is this scenario possible?

Example:

```
id,   name,   date,        another field
id 1, NAME_A , 2018-01-01, A
id 2, NAME_A , 2018-02-01, B
id 3, NAME_A , 2018-03-01, C
```

So,

- `find(2018-02-01, "A")` should be null.
- `find(2018-02-01, "B")` should be id 2.
- `find(2018-03-01, "A")` should be null.
- `find(2018-03-01, "B")` should be null.
  find(2018-03-01, "C") should be id 3.

It should work on Oracle, H2 and Postgres. (Multi-database)

Comment: Please provide some more clarity on what you are trying to achieve here. An example will be helpful.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: @Saita . . . I can't figure out what the question is.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your original data is in table #temp you can run this:

```
declare @date datetime='2018-03-01', @value varchar(max)='C'
select top 1 id from #temp where anotherfield=@value and date>=@date order by 
date desc
```

Change parameter values to test